# ¿como importar WSQEncoder de JMRTD?

Tags: java, java-swing, imagen, biometrico

Estoy tratando de ocupar la libreria JMRTD para codificar una imagen en formato WSQ, pero no puedo usar la función WSQEncoder.encoder, esto por que no la estoy importando pero no encuentro la manera correcta solo encuentro `WSQDecoder`

```
import org.jnbis.internal.WsqDecoder;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Estoy intentando hacer algo así**

```
 WSQEncoder.encode(outputStream, bitmap, bitrate, commentText);
```

Comment: Seguro que usas [JMRTD](https://sourceforge.net/p/jmrtd/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/jmrtd/src/main/java/org/jmrtd/)?

Comment: si, en el ejemplo puse jnbis, como ejemplo por el WSQDecoder, pero mas abajo tengo ya lista la importación del JMRTD, o conoces alguna alternativa para hacer la encoder de WSQencoder

Comment: Es que esa clase sólo se ve en [forks viejos](https://github.com/E3V3A/JMRTD). En el código actual de esa librería no se ve esa clase (como puedes ver si sigues el enlace que puse en el comentario anterior) y pues... sería buscar [una versión](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=org.jnbis.internal.WsqEncoder&t=ffcm&ia=web) que la incluya